# Error downloading a laravel pakage using composer update/require

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I need to download a package on my server, i'm doing:
`php7.4 composer.phar update` (the package is already in the composer.json file) / `php7.4 composer.phar require bumbummen99/shoppingcart`, the first row is:

```
Using version ^4.2 for bumbummen99/shoppingcart
./composer.json has been updated
```

but lastly it gives me this error:

```
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content. 
[RuntimeException]
/home/alvapet/vendor/bumbummen99 does not exist and could not be created.
```

I've also tried to upload the package via ftp in the vendor directory but it gives me error550: permission denied and i've tried creating the directory bumbummen99 but it gives me the same error.

Composer version 2.0.9

Comment: Composer 2.0.9 is pretty outdated. Also, you should never run `composer update`  on your server. And finally: if the directory could not be created, did you check for the directory's permissions?

Comment: bumbummen99 is free to use, doesn't have limitations

Answer (score 0):

I just tried installing this one and its working fine the command I used was

```
composer require bumbummen99/shoppingcart
```

so if you are facing this it can mean either your composer version is causing the problem or its your directory that have the permission problems as stated by Nico Haase in above comment

Comment: on the local server worked for me flawlessly, i'm facing problems doing it on the server online via ssh